# Access object inside object without using function to get it?

Tags: javascript

I want to access an object but I don't know how.
I want to access 'ctx', but using base.ctx always returns null (is this a closure?).

```
window.base = function () {

    var c = null,
        ctx = null;

    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        c = document.getElementById("canvas");
        ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    }

}
```

I found the solution was to call a function in base that returned ctx.

```
window.base = function () {

    var c = null,
        ctx = null;

    window.addEventListener("load", function(){
        c = document.getElementById("canvas");
        ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    }

    return {
        ctx: function(){return ctx;}
    };

}
```

Then I can access ctx, but now all my accesses need to be:

```
base.ctx().setStyle = "white";
```

Rather than what I'd like which is:

```
base.ctx.setStyle = "white";
```

Is it possible? I'm thinking there's a possible solution with 'this'/scope or something, but I don't know enough JavaScript yet.

Comment: Why are yiu using window instead var obj = {}

obj.ctx = function()

Comment: The bigger problem is that you can easily run into race conditions since `ctx` is populated *asynchronously.*

Comment: @Scopi: I'll change it, thank you.

Comment: @deceze: I had no idea! Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

base is a function.

use it like this:

```
base().ctx()
```

I would write your code in this way:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var base = function () {
        return document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    }

    // Do something with base()
});
```

You can also drop the function and just use the context:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    var base = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
    // Do something
});
```

Comment: Thank you! If base was self invoking, is there a way to access ctx without using a function to get its current value?

Answer (score 0):

The answer for me was to store the values in an object called "inter", and then update the contents of that object - the changes were then visible to other code.

So then I could use:
    base.ctx.fillStyle = "white";

I have no idea why the other way didn't work!

```
var base = function () {

var fps = 60,
    canvasWidth = 300,
    canvasHeight = 200,
    scaling = 1;

function updateCanvas(){
  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

var c = null,
    cStyle = null,
    updateGraphicsCallBack = null;

function initialiseCanvas(canvasName, theCallBack){
    updateGraphicsCallBack = theCallBack;
    c = document.getElementById(canvasName);
    cStyle = c.style;
    inter.ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    inter.imageData = inter.ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
    inter.imageArray = inter.imageData.data;
    inter.buff8 = new Uint8ClampedArray(inter.imageArray.buffer);
    inter.buff32 = new Uint32Array(inter.imageArray.buffer);

    cStyle.width = canvasWidth * scaling + "px";
    cStyle.height = canvasHeight * scaling + "px";
    c.width = canvasWidth;
    c.height = canvasHeight;
    inter.ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
    inter.ctx.fillStyle="#909090";

    //mouse = (typeof window.mouseInit !== "undefined") ? window.mouseInit(c) : null;
    //if(typeof window.db !== "undefined") window.db.setOutput("debugOutput");

    requestAnimationFrame(drawLoop);
}

var oldTimeStamp = 0, timeTweak = 0;
function drawLoop(currentTimeStamp) {
    currentTime = currentTimeStamp;

    if(typeof timeChart !== "undefined") timeChart.start();  

    setTimeout(
        function() {
            requestAnimationFrame(drawLoop);
        }, (1000 - ((currentTimeStamp - oldTimeStamp) - timeTweak)) / fps);

    updateGraphicsCallBack(currentTimeStamp);

    if(typeof timeChart !== "undefined") {
        timeChart.end();
        if(timeChart.currentFrameCount() > -1){
            var difference = timeChart.currentFrameCount() - fps;
            timeTweak += difference;
            if(timeTweak<-10000) timeTweak = -10000;
            if(timeTweak>10000) timeTweak = 10000;
        }
        inter.timeTweak = timeTweak;
    }

    oldTimeStamp = currentTimeStamp;
}

var inter = {
    updateCanvas: updateCanvas,
    ctx: null,//function(){return ctx;},
    canvasWidth: canvasWidth,
    canvasHeight: canvasHeight,
    fps: fps,
    scaling: scaling,
    imageData: null,
    imageArray: null,
    buff8: null,
    buff32: null,
    timeTweak: timeTweak,
    initialiseCanvas: initialiseCanvas
};

return inter;

}();
```